# Normalizing audio output loudness (LKFS/LUFS) in DaVinci Resolve 16

Tags: audio, davinci-resolve, loudness

DaVinci Resolve 16 adds a great feature that allows applying "Normalize audio levels" on a clip using the ITU BS.1770 or EBU R128 standards, to a target level of -23 LKFS/LUFS, or similar.

However, this normalization only seems to apply to the raw audio of the clip, before any filters (such as compression) are applied to it.

Is there a way to normalize the final audio *output* loudness of a project (to a standard like -23 LUFS), after all filters and so on have been applied?

Comment: Maybe see "The Fairlight Audio Guide" on "Bouncing" a track.